# QGIS Classifications on 10km^2 square grid

Tags: qgis, classification, vector-grid

I am new to QGIS, and I have a problem that I don't know how to solve:

My goal is to have a 10km x 10km square grid of Europe where each cell of the grid is classified by land use. With just a few different categories (like forest, lake, agriculture, town...), so it will be a really rough classification, and in the end, I will have Europe as a grid with different cell colors for the different categories.

I started by putting a grid over the OpenStreetMap, but I don't know how to classify my grid cells (Should I use the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin for this?).

If you have a good solution to my problem or a totally different approach?

Comment: Have looked out if a similar dataset does not exist already? Probably landuse datasets exist and you could derive it from there.

Comment: Check out the corine land cover classification - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi2msCxnJSCAxWqMTQIHWyzDqUQFnoECBkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fland.copernicus.eu%2Fen%2Fproducts%2Fcorine-land-cover&usg=AOvVaw3f2fH4UCWjMhPMzRNH40Dr&opi=89978449